# I am working with carrierwave and there is an error unknown operator: $oid (2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, carrierwave

I am trying to upload a file and show the file data like a post.I am using carrierwave to upload a file.Here are the details
**index.html.erb**

```
    <div style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:430px;margin-top:50px;width:30%;">
                <%= form_for Post.new, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
                    <%= f.file_field :attachment , class: "filestyle"%>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                    <%= f.submit "Upload" , class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" ,style:"margin-top:8px;" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
```

**Postscontroller.rb**

```
    def index
          @posts = Post.all
          @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
       end

       def create
          @post = Post.new(post_params)
          @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])

          if @post.save
             redirect_to :action => 'index'
             flash[:notice] = "The post has been uploaded."
          else
             render "index"
          end
       end
     private
          def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:attachment,:user_id)
       end
```

**routes.rb**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
        root "users#index"
        get '/' => "users#index"
        get "/new1" => "users#new1"
        get "/new2" => "users#new2"
        get "/new3" => "users#new3"
        resources :users ,to: 'posts'
        post "/users" => "users#create"
        get "users/:id" => "users#show"
        get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
        post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
        get '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
        delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
        resources :sessions
        resources :posts
        get "users/:id/post" => "posts#index"
     end
```

When i am trying to upload a file ,then it is showing an error that
**unknown operator: $oid (2)**.I don't know why it is happening.I am new to the rails please help me out to overcome this error.

Comment: Are you using mongodb?

Comment: Yes,I am using mongodb.

Comment: Can you please share your gemfile

Comment: Yes,sure,please have alook @Sajin

Comment: can u able to find out,something @Sajin